# "Even though" and "then" in the same sentence

Tags: conjunctions

Is it grammatically correct to use *even though* and *then* in the same sentence as in the following?

> **Even though** in the beginning, Picasso's work was influenced by other
>   artists **then** Picasso developed his own style of painting, which
>   consisted of pictures of the poor in various shades of blue.

Comment: Use "later" not "then" in this case to refer to a time after "in the beginning."

Comment: @Qaz thank you,  do you think two adverbs do not fit each other at the beginning?

Comment: Are you trying to say that even though he was influenced by others at first, he still had his own style even then, or that he developed his own style after he was influenced? I assumed the latter, but you could use "even then" instead of "then" to make it clearer if it's the former.

Comment: @Qaz sorry for the confusion I feel a bit that    " even though" and " in the beginning"   don't sound natural either

Comment: Those seem fine to me.

Comment: I'm not sure that the sentence you present is grammatically incorrect, but it feels awkward to me.  I would replace **then** with **eventually** or **ultimately** — although I guess **later** is fine, too.  And (as in [AmI's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/321053/26083)), I would put a comma after "other artists", and change "Picasso developed" to "he developed".

Answer (score 1):

Even though, in the beginning, Picasso's work was influenced by other artists, he developed his own style of painting, which consisted of pictures of the poor in various shades of blue.

'In the beginning' is adverbial.  'Then' is not appropriate unless it coordinates with a conditional 'if', or is adverbial (in a separate sentence) to indicate sequence.